# How to implement a fixed-sze generic IList in C#

Tags: c#, ilist

I'm building a special collection that needs to implement the generic `IList<>` interface.  The thing is, I want the collection to act like a **non-generic fixed-size** `IList`.  I don't want the user to be able to insert or remove objects into the collection.

The `IList` interface doesn't implement the `IsFixedSize` property for some reason. So what's the best way to do this with the generic `IList` interface?  I could just let the `Insert`, `Remove` and `RemoveAt` methods throw `NotImplementedException`, and I'd be OK with that, but is there a better, more accepted way?

Tony

Comment: Please tag with the appropriate language (C#?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One typical way would be to explicitly implement the offending members of `IList` like `Add`, `Insert`, and `Remove`, so that they aren't available to people unless they actually cast your thing to `IList`.  That's how arrays do it.

Comment: This is the approach I'm going to take.    I'll implement the members I don't want to expose explicitly, and as private members.  That way, they won't show up in IntelliSense when users hover over an instance of my class.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the size of the 'list' to be changeable then just use an array.

If you don't want the collection to be editable use a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) which is a wrapper over your `IList<T>` that only allows reading the content but no addition or deletion:

```
var myList = new List<string>();
var readonlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(myList);
```